# Weird output using for loop to calculate bmi

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm getting a weird output and I'm not sure why. I'm using google colaboratory. Just can't figure out why is adding the bmi 7 times at the end of each nested list. I only need it added once. I shortened the output so its not a wall of text as well.

List

```
person_data = [
         ['John', 84.5, 184], 
         ['Ryan', 81.8, 177], 
         ['Bobby', 86.1, 190], 
         ['Pete', 92.2, 188], 
         ['Esther', 69.6, 159],
         ['Jane', 72.0, 166],
         ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]
]
```

For loop

```
for i, person in enumerate(person_data):
  for value in person_data:
    weight = person[2]
    height = person[1]
    bmi = weight / height**2
    person.append(bmi) 

person_data
```

Output when ran

```
[['John',
  84.5,
  184,
  0.025769405833129092,
  0.025769405833129092,
  0.025769405833129092,
  0.025769405833129092,
  0.025769405833129092,
  0.025769405833129092,
  0.025769405833129092],
 ['Ryan',
  81.8,
  177,
  0.026452496099377696,
  0.026452496099377696,
  0.026452496099377696,
  0.026452496099377696,
  0.026452496099377696,
  0.026452496099377696,
  0.026452496099377696],
```

Comment: It's appending the value 7 times, because there are 7 people in your list, and you have a pointless inner loop that's iterating over all of them (even though the outer loop is already doing that).

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thank you. Still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second for loop is not needed because of that it adding same value multiple times.

```
for person in person_data:
    weight = person[2]
    height = person[1]
    bmi = weight / height**2
    person.append(bmi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that inner loop and enumerate:

```
for person in person_data:
    weight = person[2]
    height = person[1]
    bmi = weight / (height ** 2)
    person.append(bmi)
```

I think you might have to adjust the units to get correct BMI numbers?

Comment: It's for a course, I thought the same thing but its in the course work as...```heights = [184, 177, 190, 188, 159, 166]
weights = [84.5, 81.8, 86.1, 92.2, 69.6, 72.0 ]
names = ['John', 'Ryan', 'Bobby', 'Pete', 'Esther', 'Jane']```

Answer (score 0):

You person.append(bmi) function is inside the nested for loop when it doesn't have to be. If you remove one indent it won't append the bmi so many times. You only want to append the bmi once per person, so it really should be within the first for loop not within the one that does the calculation.